# Cannot install android-emulator-hypervisor-driver-for-amd-processors

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, amd-processor

Cannot install android-emulator-hypervisor-driver-for-amd-processors.
I have checked previous topics on this already.
AMD Ryzen 7 on MSI B450

1. SVM is enabled on BIOS
2. Hyper-V is disabled on Windows features.

As administrator I attempt to run `silent_install.bat`.
I get the following error:

```
[SC] ControlService FAILED 1062:

The service has not been started.

[SC] DeleteService SUCCESS
[SC] StartService FAILED with error 4294967201.
```

Anything else I can try?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.